# Ignite thin client continuous query listener cannot listen to all events

Tags: ignite, gridgain

**Problem scenario:**

Start the Ignite server of one node, start one thin client and create a continuous query listener, and then use 50 threads to add 500 data to the cache concurrently.

**Problem phenomenon:**

Through the information printed on the listener, it was found that the number of events listened to each time varies, possibly 496, 499 or 500...

**Test Code:**

```
public class StartServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
    }
}
```

```
public class StartThinClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String addr = "127.0.0.1:10800";

        int threadNmu = 50;

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setAddresses(addr);

        IgniteClient client1 = Ignition.startClient(clientConfiguration);

        ClientCache<Object, Object> cache1 = client1.getOrCreateCache("test");

        ContinuousQuery<Object, Object> query = new ContinuousQuery<>();
        query.setLocalListener(new CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<?, ?>> cacheEntryEvents) throws CacheEntryListenerException {
                Iterator<CacheEntryEvent<?, ?>> iterator = cacheEntryEvents.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    CacheEntryEvent<?, ?> next = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println("----" + next.getKey());
                }
            }
        });

        cache1.query(query);

        IgniteClient client2 = Ignition.startClient(clientConfiguration);
        ClientCache<Object, Object> cache2 = client2.cache("test");

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadNmu];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new OperationInsert(cache2, i, 500, threadNmu));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        Thread.sleep(60000);

    }

    static class OperationInsert implements Runnable {

        private ClientCache<Object, Object> cache;
        private int k;
        private Integer test_rows;
        private Integer thread_cnt;

        public OperationInsert(ClientCache<Object, Object> cache, int k, Integer test_rows, Integer thread_cnt) {
            this.cache = cache;
            this.k = k;
            this.test_rows = test_rows;
            this.thread_cnt = thread_cnt;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1000000 + (test_rows/thread_cnt) * k; i < 1000000 + (test_rows/thread_cnt) * (k + 1); i++) {
                cache.put("" + i, "aaa");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Version:**

The testing program uses Ignite version 2.15.0

I attempted to insert data using one thread and did not observe any event loss. In addition, I also attempted an Ignite cluster with two or three nodes, which can still listen to all 500 events even when inserting data using multiple threads. May I ask if this issue only occurs at a single node? Are there any good solutions?

Comment: Hi, interesting issue. Just in case have you tried to use Transaction cache mode? Since you have a reproducer, you can file a Jira for this issue. https://ignite.apache.org/our-community.html#contributing

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I attempted to use transactions for insertion, but still experienced the same event loss phenomenon, which I believe should be unrelated to the cache atomic mode. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: According to comments on user list, it might be a problem with all continuous queries, not just thin client: https://lists.apache.org/thread/9ztytj2fff3b9tjl1z02cmv2k6dn17d7